# Webpack Uglify plugin returns "Killed" on Ubuntu

Tags: gulp, webpack

On my remote server (Ubuntu 14.04 x64), whenever I try to uglify my bundles, the process simply returns "Killed". When I don't uglify, it's just fine.

Has anyone run into this? When I do it on my local Mac, it's fine (although I just tested it and it took 1.4 mins).

This is my webpack.config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

function makeConfig(opts) {
    var config = {

        entry: {
            app: ['./public/scripts/main.js'],
            vendor: ['lodash', 'react', 'react/lib/ReactCSSTransitionGroup', 'react-router', 'reqwest', 'd3']
        },

        stats: {
            colors: true,
            reasons: true
        },

        output: {
            devtool: (opts.env === 'dev' ? '#eval-source-map' : ''),
            path: 'dist/scripts',
            filename: '[name].bundle.js'
        },

        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                ENV: opts.env
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor.bundle.js')
        ],

        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'jsx-loader' }
            ]
        }
    };

    if(opts.env === 'prod') {
        config.plugins.push(
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
        );
    }

    return config;
}

module.exports = makeConfig;
```

and it's called by gulp like so:

```
gulp.task('webpack', ['cleanScripts'], function(done) {
    webpack(webpackConfig, function(err, stats) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw new gutil.PluginError('webpack', err);    
        }
        else {
            done();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Same with AWS free tier micro.t2

Comment: same with aws t2.small tier. Had to upgrade it to t3.large

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As @barbuza suggested, it was a memory issue. I too am using a Digital Ocean VPS that only has 512 MB of RAM (yes, I'm cheap). That's not enough for webpack's uglify plugin. Adding 2GB of swap space on the server solved the issue. I followed this article to set that up: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: The real solution here is to dodge this problem all together -- compile locally and then use `scp`, `ftp`, or whatever to get the compiled assets on the server in the right location.

Comment: Did you observe any hardware issues hereupon? Because Digital Ocean cautions against creating swaps on its servers https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @Green I didn't, and I don't think they were advising against it when this was answered. I think you'll probably be safe doing it, but like I said in my comment above, it's best to dodge this issue entirely.

Comment: Did this in an upcloud instance and it worked the same (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04/).

Comment: thank you ! and i add it can solve also angular deployment problems too

Answer (score 9):

Same thing happened with me while Digital Ocean VPS using, as mentioned above - that happens because of  building takes to much RAM for your machine, so it's "out of memory usage".

To solve this you can minimize RAM usage while file compiling via `---max_old_space_size` option, here is an advanced example of usage

```
node --max_old_space_size=1096 node_modules/webpack/.bin/webpack.js
```

Of course you can choose any size, also you can do the same with webpack-dev-server. And you don't need to add the swap space until it will be really needed for other purposes, such as you run this command only once to compile the bundle.js file.

Comment: This is the easiest option.  Just make `max_old_space_size` a fair amount smaller than your server's RAM and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on digital ocean vm, it turned out there was no swap configured, so it just run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run ng build on your local machine and then copy the dist folder to your remote like this:

```
scp -r path/to/local/folder user@x.x.x.x:/path/to/remote/folder
```