# Why does Angular-CLI 'ng build' shows "Killed"?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I added a new module, `ng build` process just getting `killed`.

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

as from this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3260#issuecomment-269666665) here:

> I think this is a memory issue. Linux will kill processes when it's
>   low on memory. See
>   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747314/webpack-uglify-plugin-returns-killed-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 30):

This is a memory problem. If you can't add extra physical memory, you could create a swap file to add extra RAM memory.

```
// Create a swapfile
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile

// Set up the swapspace
sudo mkswap /swapfile

// enable swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

The swapfile won't be recreated if you reboot. In case you want your swapfile to be permanent, edit the stab file with `sudo nano fstab`  and add the following line to it:

```
/swapfile   none    swap    sw    0   0
```

Comment: This did it for me. I had to use an server provided by the university with a 1 GB RAM limitation. Thank you!

Comment: That answer saved my life. I'm using a cheap sandbox server with little memory and I couldn't build it.
I still needed to use these flags:
ng build --prod --optimization = false --sourceMap = false

Comment: this is by far one of the most effective solution online.

Answer (score 4):

Linux will kill processes when it's low on memory which means your process is eating more memory than there is available. To regulate Node's memory usage you can use:

```
node --max_old_space_size=1096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

where 1096 can be replaced by the memory you have left

Another solution is to add memory, or free it. This can be done by adding swap for example

Answer (score 1):

I also face this problem on **Linux Server**.
This is **memory issue**. 
Linux server is not enough for webpack's uglify plugin,
So **Adding extra memory space** on the server solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

***For Centos 7***

An addition to Kurt's answer.
Creating a swap file in `Centos 7` won't work with the suggested commands.
The `fallocate` command does not work well in `Centos 7` and creates the following error when calling `swapon`:

```
swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument
```

Also you are advised to change permissions of file to 0600 before enabling swap file.
So, eventually you can do the following:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=4096 bs=1MiB
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```