# Angular prod build in Jenkins is failing

Tags: angular, jenkins, npm

I have an Angular app that I'm trying to deploy through Jenkins.  The standard DEV build works fine, but when I do a `ng build --prod` it says "ng: command not found".

When running a command with `npm run ng build -- --prod`, it says "line 1:  6910 Killed " followed by the failed command

Last week, I could get a prod build to finish successfully, but not pick up the environment.prod.ts file.  Today, I get one of the two above errors.

I've tried the following build commands:

```
sh "ng build --prod"
sh "npm run ng build -- --configuration=production"
sh "npm run ng build -- --configuration production"
sh "npm run ng build -- --configuration=production --target=production --environment=prod"
sh "npm run ng build --configuration=production --target=production --environment=prod"
sh "npm run ng build -- --prod"
sh "npm run ng build -- --configuration prod"
sh "npm run ng build -- --configuration production"
sh "npm run ng build myCoolProjectName --prod --configuration=production"
sh "npm run ng build myCoolProjectName --prod --configuration production"
sh "npm run ng build --prod --configuration=production"
sh "npm run ng build --prod --configuration production"
sh "npm run ng build --configuration=production"
```

I'm running the following versions on my Jenkins server's AWS EC2 instance:
Angular CLI: 12.0.3,
Node: 16.2.0,
Package Manager: npm 7.13.0,
OS: linux x64

Here's the important parts of my Jenkinsfile:

```
 tools {
    //nodejs 'NodeJS 12.18.1'
    nodejs 'NodeJS 16.2.0'
  }

 stage('npm install') {
    steps {
            sh 'npm install'
    }
  }

  stage('Build') {
    steps {
      script{
        if("${ENVIRO}" == "prod") {
          PROFILE = "my-prod"
          sh "npm run ng build -- --prod"
        } else if("${ENVIRO}" == "qa"){
          PROFILE = "my-qa"
          sh "npm run ng build -- --configuration production"
        } 
        else {
          PROFILE = "my-dev"
          sh "npm run ng build"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Edit:
I added a screenshot of the memory usage.  The swiggle on the end of the red line is when I did a build(it failed).  It seems to have plenty available.
[image: Memory usage from the Jenkins server. It barely uses any.]

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'd be happy to supply more info.

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 1 killed most likely happens because the machine in the clouds (on Jenkins) is running out of memory.

Try adding memory to the machine or killing processes that are taking memory so the Angular build has more memory to operate on.

You can also try running this:

```
// make node.js process take 1.5GB of space
node --max_old_space_size=1500 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build -- --prod
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45429555/7365461) for more info.

Comment: I added a screenshot from the server.  It seems to have a lot of memory available.

Comment: Does it work locally? Try to get an environment as close to as Jenkins locally and see if it can be reproduced.

Comment: I can do local prod builds successfully, yes.  I then manually put the files on the server and everything is ok that way.

Comment: The max_old_space command didnt work for me, but upgrading my AWS EC2 instance from t2.small to t2.medium did the trick.  Thank you!